# In Angular Spec how to refactor the setter so that it actually refers to the property 'value'

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my angular 4, I am writing a test case in spec file, and I mocked my form like below:

```
  const form = <NgForm>{
    value: {
      lastName: 'test',
      firstName: 'temp'
    },
    reset() {
    },
    setValue(val: any) {
    }
  };
```

I get an error saying 'Refactor this setter so that it actually refers to the property 'value' '. What does that mean?

Comment: please keep removing them and see which one is causing the error

Comment: removing didn't help

Comment: so your issue might not be related to this code

Comment: remove casting NgForm as well